# select box won't resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue where I have a dropdown box that is as wide as the words "choose please"
but when I append to the box it adds the new options to the dropdown but is stays the same width even though the new option are much wider. How do I force it to update the width.

```
 var sOption = '
<option value="volvo">Volvoooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="opel">Opel</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>';

$("mySelect").append(sOption); // how do I force the width to update
```

Comment: If you do it without jQuery will the select box size grow? If not it's probably a CSS issue.

Comment: as already said, your script itself works, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MfNTH/1).. if you add your styles, we can have a closer look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is CSS-relative. By default, it works well: http://jsfiddle.net/featalion/A6qbd/. So, try to update your width style to automatic resize the select: http://jsfiddle.net/featalion/f5QWH/1/.

`$('#my_select').css('width', 'auto');`

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like you have some css forcing the width thinner I would start with

```
.mySelect{width:auto;}
```

and go from there